# Could not determine the order of year, month, and date from 'M/yy/d'

Tags: .net, parsing, datetime, formatting, date-format

When I run:
`Date.Parse(Now.ToString("M/yy/d"), New Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo() With {.ShortDatePattern = "M/yy/d"})`

I am getting the error:

```
Could not determine the order of year, month, and date from 'M/yy/d'.
```

Is this (strange) format somewhere prohibited? Is it a bug?

Note
 
I do not know why this format is required.

**Edit**
Proposed `Date.ParseExact(Now.ToString("M/yy/d"), "M/yy/d",New Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo() )`
gives:

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

**Edit2**
I am using NET Framework 4.0 (windows).

Comment: Does `.ParseExact` work?

Comment: @Jon: Result added to question (doesn't work).

Comment: What's the output when you echo/print `Now.ToString("M/yy/d")`?

Comment: Strange really... [works for me here](http://ideone.com/aG5au).

Comment: Which version of the .NET Framework are you using?

Comment: @Jon: The third writeline gives exceptiton for me.

Comment: @IvanH: I got it, have a look below.

Comment: @IvanH, the date separator is why I wanted you to print the output.  I was thinking along the lines of Jon's accepted answer below, but wasn't certain. Glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a result of two components:

1. Your current culture uses a different date separator than the invariant culture default (`/`).
2. When `/` is used as part of a format string in `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` it is [not translated as a literal forward slash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) but rather *as the date separator character from the specified format provider, whatever that is* (if you want it to be taken literally, you must use the "escape sequence" `%/`).

So there are many ways to do this correctly:

```
Date.ParseExact(Now.ToString("M/yy/d"), "M%/yy%/d", Nothing)
```

This simply tells `ParseExact` to interpret the slashes literally.

```
Date.ParseExact(Now.ToString("M/yy/d"), "M/yy/d",
              New Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo() With {.DateSeparator = "/"})
```

This tells `ParseExact` to use a literal slash as the date separator, changing its default behavior for your current culture.

As an aside: I 'm using `ParseExact` instead of `Parse` because it is the better fit when you know that the input has a specific format; `Parse` attempts to determine the format on its own using heuristics, which is not appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but the code is outdated. The accepted answer details the reasons why this happens +1 for that.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("11/11/1997", "MM/dd/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None);
```